`bot` is not defined when i try to run nodemon[js]
so, when i tried running my discord bot, it crashed and said that bot was not defined(??) and i need sum help, so i have my code so you can have a look
require('dotenv').config();
const { Client, IntentsBitField, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const prefix = "!"
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
  ],
});

client.on('ready', (c) => {
  console.log(`✅ ${c.user.tag} is online.`);
});



client.on('ready', (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) {
        return;
      }
    let content = message.content

    if (content === "!roll") { 
      const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor(0x0099FF)
    .setTitle('Some title')
    .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
    .setAuthor({ name: 'Some name', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', url: 'https://discord.js.org' })
    .setDescription('Some description here')
    .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
        { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
    )
    .addFields({ name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true })
    .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter({ text: 'Some footer text here', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png' }); 
  message.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] }); 
    }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)

i was expecting the bot to run and do what it had to do

What is the actual error message?

There's nothing wrong with your code. It seems like you tried to call 'bot' below this code. You named the variable client in your code:
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
    IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
  ],
});

so replace any code that declares bot with client.
